# Is Key Bunch a proper word?

Tags: single-word-requests, is-it-a-word

When you want to describe a set of keys bound to a huge metal ring, like the ones you'd see in a game of movie with medieval settings on the belt of a prison guard,  what word would you use? Key bunch? Key bundle? Key ring? Or just plain Keys? For example, does the sentence,

> "We have to steal his key bunch to escape,"

sound proper English? If not, how would you describe the keys?

Comment: Normally it would be called a "key ring". Here's a [Google Image Search](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1OKWM_enUS764US764&biw=1177&bih=640&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=h9ykW9ngLMKU0gKZvJD4AQ&q=old-fashioned+key+ring&oq=old-fashioned+key+ring&gs_l=img.3..0i30.33706.36578..37841...0.0..0.139.1673.0j14......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i7i30.CwpS-9oYkMw) for "old-fashioned key ring".

Comment: I would say _We have to steal his keys to escape_ unless there was some specific reason to describe them as being on such a key ring.  Most people would assume that _keys_ would refer to a number of keys on some sort of key ring rather than a bunch of loose keys.  There is a character in the film E.T. who is known for the ring of keys hanging on the actor's belt and that character is simply called _[Keys](https://www.shmoop.com/et-the-extra-terrestrial/peter-coyote.html)_.

Comment: There is nothing technically wrong with "key bunch" -- it's a bunch of keys.  Not particularly idiomatic for the US Midwest, though.  As Roger suggests, simply saying "steal his keys" would clearly and idiomatically convey the meaning.

Comment: @HotLicks In the UK 'his key bunch' would not usually be said. 'His bunch of keys' might be but 'bunch of keys' is more likely to be used when describing someone or when talking about keys not associated with a person. "The prison officer had a large bunch of keys" or "There was a large bunch of keys lying on the desk" would both be common but "We need to get hold of his bunch of keys" would be less likely than "We need to get hold of his keys".

Comment: If you say "his key bunch" I will understand you, but I will suspect that English is not your native language.

Answer (score 1):

This is either a [key ring](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/key-ring) (dictionary.com) or [ring of keys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMAuesRJm1E) (YouTube) as in the Tony Award-winning song from the musical *Fun Home*. A "key ring" can be either the bare ring, without the keys, or the ring and keys together.

Comment: Also "key chain" ... in case the connecting method for the keys is not actually a ring.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a "bunch of keys"

> A bunch of keys alike a bunch of grapes or bunch of pigeons is a
>   collective noun showcasing an image of a set of keys.

https://www.quora.com/What-is-meant-by-a-bunch-of-keys.

But to me it also means a LOT of keys you would never call a set of keys you can count by sight a "bunch" it has a connotation of many keys, "wow that is a large bunch of keys"